# Need to find the horizontal asymptotes of a given expression.

Tags: calculus, rational-functions

I need to determine the horizontal asymptotes of the following expression:$$\frac{2x^{1/3}}{(1x^2+4)^{1/6}}$$
I’m not even sure where to begin. I understand I need to divide all terms by the highest degree in the denominator (which normally I’d assume was $x^2$), but I’m unsure of how to interpret it since it’s contained within the 6th root radicand. The third root in the numerator throws me off as well. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: The numerator is $\bigl( x^2 \cdot \bigl( 1 + \frac{4}{x^2} \bigr) \bigr)^{1/6}$. Can you figure out how to continue from there?

Comment: @HansLundmark Honestly.. no.

Comment: You realise that $x^{1/3}=(x^2)^{1/6}$, don't you? :-)

Comment: @Dominique I do now, but I’m not connecting the dots. I still don’t know how to proceed with this 6th root. I’m assuming that whatever value I divide the term $x^2$ by must be a number such that the 6th root yields $x^2$.

Comment: Perhaps you also know that $(a \cdot b)^{1/6} = a^{1/6} \cdot b^{1/6}$ (for nonnegative $a$ and $b$)?

Answer (score 0):

I shall assume here that $x \in \mathbb R ^ +$, because defining fractional powers of negative numbers is *tedious* in $\mathbb R$ (you could define $x^{\frac 1 p}$ for $x < 0$ when $p$ is odd by $x^{\frac 1 p} = -\left((-x)^{\frac 1 p}\right)$, but then you would get $\left((-1)^2\right)^\frac 1 6 = 1$ but $(-1)^\frac 2 6 = (-1)^\frac 1 3 = -1$ and $\left((-1)^\frac 1 6\right)^2$ undefined...)

Then the equality $(x^a)^b = x^{ab}$ is valid for any $x \gt 0$ and $(a,b)\in\mathbb R^2$. Hence:

$$\frac{2x^\frac 1 3}{(1x^2+4)^\frac 1 6} = \frac{2x^\frac 1 3}{\left(x^2\times(1+\frac 4{x^2})\right)^\frac  1 6} = \frac{2x^\frac 1 3}{x^\frac 1 3(1+\frac 4 {x^2})^\frac 1 6} = \frac 2 {(1+\frac 4 {x^2})^\frac 1 6}$$

And you can conclude:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}{\frac 1 {x^2}} = 0 \implies\lim_{x\to\infty}{\frac 1{1+\frac 4 {x^2}}} = 1 \implies\lim_{x\to\infty}{\frac 2{(1+\frac 4 {x^2})^\frac 1 6}}= 2
 \implies\lim_{x\to\infty}{\frac{2x^\frac 1 3}{(1x^2+4)^\frac 1 6}}=2$$

Comment: Thank you so much!